# JavaFX - Show Alert Dialog within ChangeListener event

Tags: java, javafx, spinner, alert, changelistener

I want to show a alert dialog when the valueProperty of a spinner is changed. Therefore i've added a ChangeListener to my valueProperty:

```java
this.spinnerColumns.setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(2,20));

this.spinnerColumns.getValueFactory().valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

  if(oldValue > newValue) {
    // Ask for permission
    System.out.println("Ask for permission");
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
    alert.setTitle("Error");
    alert.setHeaderText("Ask something...");
    alert.showAndWait();

    if(alert.getResult() == ButtonType.OK) {
      // do something
    }
  }
});
```

This code is not working properly. When the Alert is showing, the spinner keeps decreasing his value until the min value is reached. Some suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to stop spinning without using reflection as far as I know... Try this code.

```
if(oldValue > newValue) {

    try {
        Skin<?> skin = this.spinnerColumns.getSkin();
        Object behavior = skin.getClass().getMethod("getBehavior").invoke(skin);
        behavior.getClass().getMethod("stopSpinning").invoke(behavior);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return; // If refleciton failed, do nothing
    }

    // Ask for permission
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Bug [JDK-8089332](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089332)
and is similar to Bug [JDK-8252863](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8252863).
The workaround there leads to:

```
this.spinnerColumns.setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(2, 20));

this.spinnerColumns.getValueFactory().valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    Node increment = spinnerColumns.lookup(".increment-arrow-button");
    if (increment != null) {
        increment.getOnMouseReleased().handle(null);
    }

    Node decrement = spinnerColumns.lookup(".decrement-arrow-button");
    if (decrement != null) {
        decrement.getOnMouseReleased().handle(null);
    }

    if (oldValue > newValue) {
        // Ask for permission
        System.out.println("Ask for permission");
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setHeaderText("Ask something...");
        alert.showAndWait();

        if (alert.getResult() == ButtonType.OK) {
            // do something
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Allready discussed in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933513/javafx-spinner-keeps-going-after-removed-from-scene